# Android AsyncTask called "multiple" times

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm fairly new to android programming. I have a main activity that gets data from a DB through a service handler (url). I want to insert data as well, but on a different activity, and i want my main activity to be up to date each time its been called (onresume(),onrestart()).
I've found this on the Android API reference about AsyncTask:
*The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)*
Does that mean that i cannot call the AsyncTask whenever the activity resumes, or that i cannot have multiple "instances" of the AsyncTask running at the same time?

Comment: You can create multiple instance of the same Async Task and execute them at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It literally means, that while `AsyncTask` is running, you cannot launch it again.
In your `MainActivity.class` you have line:

```
task.execute();
```

if task either is finished or not and you call the method again then `exception` will be thrown.

And put this method in `onResume`() is a good practice.
Only one thing to notice is: if you put in `onRestart`() remember, this callback works when you change configuration, but it will not be called if you Create `activity`.

The doc about [lifecycle of an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that i cannot call the AsyncTask whenever the activity resumes, or that i cannot have multiple "instances" of the AsyncTask running at the same time?

It means you cannot call the `execute` method twice on the same `AsyncTask` instance regardless it is completed or not.